# How can we write typescript and run with node directly?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write some simple typescripts.
Have the below setup but not works.

> node  src/getExchangeAndTickerList.ts

```
import * as mkdirp from 'mkdirp';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "ES2018",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
          "*": [ "./*" ],
      },
      "types": ["node"]
  },    
  "include": [
      "./src/**/*.ts",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have to compile it to javascript first.

Comment: use ts-node if you don't want to transpile or run it in Deno

Comment: There's deno, something like a node alternative, that can natively run TS.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla `node` can only execute Javascript code. If you want to run Typescript code, you have two solutions:

- Use a tool registering `.ts` files, like [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node).
- Transpile your Typescript code using the `tsc` command. This will generate the Javascript version of your files.